# Unable to Read Request Body in Action Filter

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following curl command:

```sh
curl  -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  -X POST http://localhost:9000/go
```

the action filter below does not log the content of the request body:

```scala
import akka.stream.Materializer
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Logging
import play.api.mvc.{ActionFilter, PlayBodyParsers, Request, Result}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class SomeActionFilter @Inject()(parse: PlayBodyParsers)(
  implicit materializer: Materializer,
  val executionContext: ExecutionContext
) extends ActionFilter[Request]
    with Logging {
  override protected def filter[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Option[Result]] =
    parse.formUrlEncoded.apply(request).run().map {
      case Left(result) => Some(result)
      case Right(formUrl) =>
        logger.info(formUrl.toString)
        None
    }
}
```

Why not? The branch of code leading to the Right(formUrl) does get executed but the output to the log is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by the Playframework team [here](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/unable-to-materialise-request-body-in-action-filter/5056) by using casting as follows:

```scala
request.asInstanceOf[Request[AnyContent]].body.asFormUrlEncoded
```